# Unirest form fields not being sent correctly from Jython

Tags: java, http, jython, unirest

I'm using java Unirest (1.4.7) implementation from both Jython (2.7) and Java (7) code.

I've encountered an issue when sending http requests from Jython code :

Here is the Jython code :

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest as Unirest;
r = Unirest.post("http://localhost:5002/test").field(u"this", u"makes").field(u"no", u"sense").asString();
```

This gives me the following request body when i print it server side :

```
no=sense&this=m&this=a&this=k&this=e&this=s
```

The first "field" is always "scattered" in the request body as if it was a collection.

Now, if i do the same thing in Java :

```
try {
    Unirest.post("http://localhost:5002/test")
    .field("this", "makes")
    .field("no", "sense")
    .asString();
} catch (UnirestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this body on the server, which is the one i expected :

```
no=sense&this=makes
```

The headers are exactly the same in both case (Excepted, obviously for the body content-length), the only thing that change is the body.

**What is wrong with my Jython code ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the jython Strings are somehow seen as Collections by Unirest on the first time i pass them as a field. I'm not exactly sure why, but using this intuition I managed a workaround for my Jython code.

Explicitly turning Jython String into Java String, something that is usually not required as far as i know, fixed my problem.

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest as Unirest;
import java.lang.String as jstr

Unirest.post("http://localhost:5002/test").field(jstr(u"this"), jstr(u"makes")).field(jstr(u"no"), jstr(u"sense")).asString();
```

Now produces the expected request body :

```
no=sense&this=makes
```